# XCode : How to Add Left and Right Padding on Text Field?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have this .h code :

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *fieldEmail;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *fieldPassword;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *titleLogin;

- (IBAction)buttonRegister;
- (IBAction)buttonLogin;
- (IBAction)loginFacebook;
- (IBAction)loginTwitter;

@end
```

and this is my .m code :

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [_fieldEmail setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"ABeeZee-Regular" size:14]];
    [_titleLogin setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Raleway-ExtraLight" size:28]];

    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)buttonRegister {
}

- (IBAction)buttonLogin {
}

- (IBAction)loginFacebook {
}

- (IBAction)loginTwitter {
}
@end
```

now, what I want to do is to add padding on left and right of these 2 text fields : `fieldEmail` and `fieldPassword` so it has some space because I put an image as background on both text fields.

I tried to add this code on my .m file under `- (void)viewDidLoad` :

```
UIView *fieldEmail = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 10, 10)];
[UITextField setLeftViewMode:UITextFieldViewModeAlways];
[UITextField setLeftView:fieldEmail];
```

but my XCode gave me this error message :

```
no known class method for selector 'setLeftViewMode'
no known class method for selector 'setLeftView'
```

by the way, I'm using XCode 4.6.3. does this version have special code to add padding on text field? thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`leftViewMode` and `leftView` are properties of `UITextField`, *not class methods*. You need to assign them to instances.

```
yourTextField.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;
yourTextField.leftView     = fieldEmail;
```